# debugging with try and catch statements in MATLAB

Tags: debugging, matlab, editor

I have a try/catch statement in a MATLAB file that calls a bunch of nested functions. Simply, the try/catch is running at the 'top' level, iterating about a filelist for which I call functions on.

```
for i=1:length(FILELIST)
try
dosomething(FILELIST(i)
catch
disp(exception.message)
rethrow(exception)
end
```

My question is, say dosomething() has many subfunctions dosomethingchild() how can I access the debug workspace of that? I would have to remove the try/catch statements in all parents in order to access the debug workspace with 'STop if errors/warnings' set to full.

try/catch is making it harder to debug, but I want to keep it because sometimes the code will fail on some files because of the nature of the files...not the code itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove that `try..catch`. Since you are only displaying and rethrowing the error, without actually catching anything specific, it is not viable production code to be robust towards error caused by the nature of your files. It will act the same as without the `try..catch`, so after an error it will stop execution.

With `stop if error` enabled, it will stop in your error handler, which is useless as you already noticed. From there it is impossible to return to the workspace of your called functions, because those workspaces have already been closed (the calls have already returned).

In a real-life situation, you could also try `dbstop if caught error` together with your `try..catch`, but in this case I'd advise to either get rid of the `try..catch` or at least make it catch specific errors. You'd also may want to catch the (specific) errors as soon as they occur; the farther away from the actual occurrence, the less sense a specific error usually makes.

Answer (score 1):

why not add  `keyboard` to your catch statement and inspect what's going on when your code fails.

Comment: This can cause problems if you want to keep the try/catch in the released code.

Answer (score 0):

Generall I agree with [Egon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400067/5763431) that your try/catch block doesn't help at all. However, for your debugging case it might not be the worst idea. My suggestion for debugging this code:

1. Remove the rethrow, and execute `dbstop if error` to switch to debug mode as soon as an error occurs. Alternatively, put a breakpoint on the line with the `disp(execption.message)`.
2. Now you have two things you can do:

   - Run the script, and when an error occurs that definitely is caused by an invalid input file you can catch the error and actually handle it (usually printing an error message that the file with the name xyz.csv has been ignored)
   - If you do not  know the source of the error, you can *now* put a breakpoint in your `doSomething()` function, prefereable as close to the error as possible (the error gives you the call stack, so you should get pretty close) and then execute `doSomething()` again manually from the console. It will stop at your breakpoint and then you can step through (Shortcut: F10) or also step into you sub-functions (step In, F11).
3. Sometimes the error message occurs after the original error occurs, then you will have to repeat those steps. However, once you are in a function you have the complete workspace of that function available and can thus execute all previous commands manually (again) to backtrack where things went wrong.